Link two dmn's in drools workbench 7.74
I have two dmn's in my project , I have to link both dmn's that is when i trigger rules present in first dmn , the first dmn rules output should trigger the second dmn rules and output should be from the second dmn.





This "question" doesn't appears to be program-related?
